# Tkinter button open another window that i don't want

Tags: python, tkinter

as I say in the title, when I click on a button (analyse) another windows open and I don't want it. The problems is, in the analyse function, the first line is an import of my tkinter file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried to delete the import and the second windows does not pop up, so I am pretty sure it is the problem. Moreover I need to do this import in the analyse function because I already import the other module in my tkinter file

tkinter file :

```py
import fileb

def analyser():
    output=fileb.analyse(name)

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.geometry("800x500")
label = Label(fenetre, text='Emotion Video')
label.pack()

boutonanalyse=Button(fenetre, text='analyze', command=analyser)
boutonanalyse.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

fileb :

```py
def analyse(name):
    import tkinter_essais
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import your Tkinter file, you are running that file. This means that the code is run twice and so you have two windows opened up. A way to bypass this is by putting your tkinter setup into a function, and having that run if it is the main program only using something like this:

```
import fileb

def analyser():
    output=fileb.analyse(name)

def tkSetup():
    fenetre = Tk()
    fenetre.geometry("800x500")
    label = Label(fenetre, text='Emotion Video')
    label.pack()

    boutonanalyse=Button(fenetre, text='analyze', command=analyser)
    boutonanalyse.pack(side=BOTTOM)

if "__name__" == "__main__":
    tkSetup()
```

The if name == main checks if the program is being run originally (best way I can think to describe it) and so it wont be run if you import the file.